# Stored procedure is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure to retrieve some details based on the certain values passed to a parameter. THis requires switching between the SQLs to be executed by stored procedure. Following is the code:

```
USE [DFS]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DAFS]
@EmailID Nvarchar(128),
@clientID int,
@userType Varchar(50),
@Success numeric output, 
@msg varchar(100) output  

AS

BEGIN
    if @userType='Normal User'
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Allcdn 
                    WHERE EmailID = @EmailID AND ClientID = @clientID) 
            begin
                set @Success=0
                set @msg='Carry on ....'
            end
        else
            begin
                set @Success=6  
                set @msg='Not allowed ...' 
            END
        end
    else
        Begin
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Alcon 
                        WHERE EmailID = @EmailID AND ClientID = @clientID) 
                BEGIN
                    set @Success=0
                    set @msg='Carry on...' 
                END 
            END
        End
    end
END
```

The entire processing is based on the variable @userType. Not sure why the stored procedure is not compiling.

Comment: Forgot to add that we are using SQL Server 2008 database.

Comment: What do you mean "not working" and "not compiling"?  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formatting is your friend, just with a quick glance, it appears you have too many `END`s -- See [SQL Fiddle with working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85aff):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DAFS]
  @EmailID Nvarchar(128),
  @clientID int,
  @userType Varchar(50),
  @Success numeric output, 
  @msg varchar(100) output  

AS
BEGIN
  if @userType='Normal User'
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Allcdn 
                WHERE EmailID = @EmailID AND ClientID = @clientID) 
      begin
        set @Success=0
        set @msg='Carry on ....'
      end
    else
      begin
        set @Success=6  
        set @msg='Not allowed ...' 
      END
  else
    Begin
      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Alcon 
                    WHERE EmailID = @EmailID AND ClientID = @clientID)
        BEGIN
          set @Success=0
          set @msg='Carry on...' 
        END 
    END
end
```

Comment: Just noticed that as soon as I finished formatting the wall of code.  To clarify, the `IF... ELSE` statements don't need ending `END`s.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables correct, there are way too many ENDs in this proc

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables this just shows the importance of formatting and indenting code.  Otherwise it becomes a mess to find the issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fix and tips for code maintenance.